# Yaml code fails while running msg: "{{ job_info[0][\"JOB_NAME\"] }}"

Tags: ansible, yaml

Here is my Yaml code.

```yaml
---
- hosts: as053a
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - ibm.power_ibmi
  vars:
    job_info: ""
  tasks:
    - name: Submit a batch job and run CALL QGPL/PGM1
      ibm.power_ibmi.ibmi_submit_job:
        cmd: DSPPTF OUTPUT(*PRINT)
    - name: Get status of a list of jobs
      ibm.power_ibmi.ibmi_job:
        user: MSRXS
        type: "*BATCH"
      register: job_info
    - name: Debug job info
      debug:
        var: job_info
    - name: Print the job name or names
      debug:
         msg: "{{ job_info[0][\"JOB_NAME\"] }}"
```

Basically I'm trying to run a command & get the process ID & other details from a IBMi system.
Out of the four tasks, 3 tasks run successfully, but the fourth task fails with below error message:

> fatal: [as053a]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/bwrap_7266694_r5nf2p16/awx_7266694_2sgugv1b/project/as053a.dspptf.yaml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n        var: job_info\n    - name: Print the job name or names\n      ^ here\n"}

Please let me what needs to be done

The output of third task looks like below:

```json
"job_info": {
        "end": "2023-02-18 05:03:14.796003",
        "job_log": [],
        "failed": false,
        "changed": false,
        "job_info": [
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-17 23:02:23",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "927415/MSRXS/QPADEV000C",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-17 23:02:23",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "927529/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "ABNORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-17 23:02:23",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDED DUE TO THE MESSAGE SEVERITY LEVEL BEING EXCEEDED",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": "",
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-17 23:55:28",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-17 23:55:28",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "928197/MSRXS/QPRTJOB",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "ALTERNATE_SPOOL_USER",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "ABNORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 10
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 00:40:00",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "928201/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 00:39:59",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "928748/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 00:40:00",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:05:01",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:05:00",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "931583/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:05:00",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:29:54",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:29:53",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932009/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:29:53",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:36:25",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:36:24",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932122/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:36:24",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:41:44",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:41:44",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932232/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:41:44",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:59:55",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:59:55",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932541/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 04:59:55",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:01:32",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:00:28",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932558/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:01:32",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            },
            {
                "JOB_STATUS": "OUTQ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_NAME": "IBMSAJOBQ",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_TYPE": "BCH",
                "JOB_ACCOUNTING_CODE": "IBM 123385 897",
                "CCSID": 37,
                "JOB_END_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:03:13",
                "SUBMITTER_JOB_NAME": "915387/QUSER/QSQSRVR",
                "JOB_ENTERED_SYSTEM_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:03:12",
                "JOB_DESCRIPTION": "ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_INFORMATION": "YES",
                "JOB_NAME": "932641/MSRXS/ISYSJOBD",
                "JOB_TYPE_ENHANCED": "BATCH",
                "COMPLETION_STATUS": "NORMAL",
                "JOB_DATE": "",
                "JOB_ACTIVE_TIME": "2023-02-18 05:03:12",
                "JOB_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "ISYSMODOBJ",
                "JOB_QUEUE_STATUS": "RELEASED",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE": "MSRXS",
                "JOB_SUBSYSTEM": "",
                "SUBMITTER_MESSAGE_QUEUE_LIBRARY": "QUSRSYS",
                "JOB_SCHEDULED_TIME": "",
                "JOB_END_REASON": "JOB ENDING IN NORMAL MANNER",
                "JOB_QUEUE_PRIORITY": "",
                "JOB_END_SEVERITY": 30
            }
        ],
        "start": "2023-02-18 05:03:14.707204",
        "delta": "0:00:00.088799",
        "rc": 0
    },
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

I tried changing the syntax of fourth tasks in various ways. But it keeps failing.

Comment: => ` msg: "{{ job_info.job_info[0].JOB_NAME }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of variable names makes this look more confusing. the `ibm.power_ibmi.ibmi_job` documents these [return values](https://ibm.github.io/ansible-for-i/modules/ibmi_job.html#return-values). As you see it will retrun you a dict of which there will be an attribute `job_info` which is a list. Since your register your task output also as `job_info` you would need to access it as

```yaml
    - name: Print the job name or names
      debug:
         msg: "{{ job_info.[\"job_info\"][0][\"JOB_NAME\"] }}"
```

since the first job_info is the name of your var, then the second job info is an attribute of the dict which is your var. then you will be able to access the list using index [0] then lastly lookup then job name from the first index